# Anonymous clear web server?

Tags: torproject.org

I was wondering if it is possible to set up a web server, on the clear web that is completely anonymous. Perhaps using a tor proxy?
Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You may create an anonymous website at any time by just not registering any domain, and letting people access it by typing its IP address. That way, your website will have no name at all.